# Display metabox title for custom fields with values

Tags: custom-field, loop, metabox, php

I'm using multiple metabox panels in my write posts. IN my functions I'm registering multiple metaboxes:

```
$prefix = 'dbt_';

$meta_boxes = array();

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'general_information',
    'title' => 'General Information',
    'pages' => array('post', 'page', 'link'), // multiple post types, accept custom post types
    'context' => 'normal', // normal, advanced, side (optional)
    'priority' => 'high', // high, low (optional)
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'id' => $prefix . 'name',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => 'default value here'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Manufacturer',
            'id' => $prefix . 'manufacturer',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        )

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'measurements',
    'title' => 'Measurements',
    'pages' => array('post', 'page', 'link'), // multiple post types, accept custom post types
    'context' => 'normal', // normal, advanced, side (optional)
    'priority' => 'high', // high, low (optional)
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Length',
            'id' => $prefix . 'length',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Width',
            'id' => $prefix . 'width',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        )

..etc
```

In my theme I'm displaying the name and values of each field in each metabox group. The goal is to have fields grouped by metaboxes otherwise I would just use `get_post_custom($post_id)`.

Code in single.php:

```
global $meta_boxes;

foreach ( $meta_boxes as $metabox ) {
echo $metabox['title'];
  foreach ( $metabox['fields'] as $field ) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true); //get post meta from each metabox
    if(!isset($meta[0])) continue; //display only fields with values
    echo $field['name'];
    echo $meta ? $meta : $field['std']; //show value or default value
  }
}
```

If for instance a metabox has no fields with values, the metabox title `$metabox['title']` still appears. How can I hide the metabox title if no values exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another simple foreach loop to check if you have any values first:

```
foreach ( $meta_boxes as $metabox ) {
    $has_value = false
    foreach ( $metabox['fields'] as $field ) {
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true); 
        if(!isset($meta[0])){
            $need_title = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($has_value){
        echo $metabox['title'];
        foreach ( $metabox['fields'] as $field ) {
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true); //get post meta from each metabox
            if(!isset($meta[0])) continue; //display only fields with values
            echo $field['name'];
            echo $meta ? $meta : $field['std']; //show value or default value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea Bainternet, thanks! Instead of having the `$need_title` var I just echo the metabox title where `if(isset($meta[0]))`